# What causes a fat Chrome scrollbar and how to fix?

Tags: google-chrome

Sometimes when I use chrome I get a 'fat' scrollbar. What causes this? It's not just on sites I develop, but (such as in the screenshot) sites such as Stack Overflow as well.

On a site I'm developing I hide the scrollbar by using negative margin. So when it appears fat it looks like there are errors in the UI.

There are no JavaScript errors in the console. If I go to the same sites in other browsers (Firefox, Edge, IE) the scrollbar appears as normal.

[image]

Comment: Why close? at least there should be a CSS workaround for this....

Comment: Same problem as mentioned here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ViYbXA8TPCA

Comment: I have found this occurs when I connect a relatively old monitor to my surface pro 4 - so i think it's a scaling bug. It happens with other apps to (including Windows File Explorer)

Comment: You're not alone. The same problems happened on surface pro 2017. Bug found after windows 10 update, I think it's windows bug.

Comment: Just to mention it happens on Chrome in my Debian too. I expect the Windows and Chrome things are unrelated.